# Some basic help about Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks

Firstly, I'd like to state that I do not have any basis to the Neural Networks and I'd like you to recommend me very simple and understandable resources.

While I have a home assignment for a short time, I would like to ask you for help for the following question.

> Within the context of Artificial Neural Networks;
>
> How is the solution / representation of **AND, OR, XOR** problems?

I can find some articles about **XOR** problem from google, but I cannot find any about **AND, OR** problems. I think and / or is special words for google and so I cannot find articles.

Thank you.

Comment: Try searching "neural network boolean logic". I found some results with that search that should help you. Also, please try to keep to one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two question: a literature question, and a concrete question. I will only answer your concrete question. Single artificial neurons compute linear threshold functions
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if} \sum_i w_i x_i \geq \theta, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
See if you can represent AND and OR in this form.